# Can Putty be used to send serial data from the PC to the PIC? How?

Tags: pic, serial

I am looking for a simple program that can send data down the serial to the PIC. I have used Putty with USB-UART converter on my laptop. I have made the PIC->PC communiation work which is frankly a trivial task.

The question is, how to do the opposite. I can't find any option in Putty to send data down the serial port. What alternative do I have? Is the only option to use custom application written in C++/C#? It is better that I be able to implement flow control (of any kind) so the PC could be told to pause sending the data.

Comment: Did you try typing the data into PuTTY directly to test it?

Comment: There is an option in PuTTY to use flow control. I always disable it because usually I don't want it.

Answer (score 6):

PuTTY works well as a general terminal emulator but for work with embedded systems I prefer [Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) which has a lot of support for working with binary / hex. When sending a file you get the option to set a delay between each character, each line and can send the same file multiple times with a delay between each time:

[image: Realterm send]

So using that you could either add delays or implement flow control (which is set on a different tab). Another alternative to using flow control is to implement one of the fairly ancient protocols like XMODEM which are fairly simple and don't consume a lot of code space, if you have a little over 1k of RAM available then I've used [this code](http://www.menie.org/georges/embedded/xmodem.html) and it works. [ExtraPuTTY](https://sourceforge.net/projects/extraputty/) is a fork of PuTTY that adds XMODEM and a few other file transfer protocols.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to send a HEX or command file ...

See [Is it possible to send the content of text file over PuTTY over serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826002/is-it-possible-to-send-the-content-of-text-file-over-putty-over-serial-port) where a solution is given using PLink (PuTTY Link, I presume) which should be part of the PuTTY install.

It's hard to ask an original question!

Answer (score 0):

Under Terminal option, on Local echo: select Force ON

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: Default option only allow to receive data from the port. I think he know how to use putty and receive data. This option allow to send data